# How to resolve 'This integration key could not be updated' error when adding a callback URL in Docusign?

Tags: php, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

i'm trying to implement docusign in my application, and i have an issues when i try to add the callback url  in the  Additional settings => Redirect URI which is "http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/ds/callback" in docusign, i got this error :** This integration key could not be updated. Please try again in a moment.**

i tried to search but didn't find anything helpful
Can you please help me understanding what is happening here or guide me to some solution
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This error has two common causes. In your case, a fragment (#) in the redirect URI rendered the url invalid, blocking the save.

The other common case is special characters (such as an ampersand) in the integration key's name. Ikey names should only use alphanumerics.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for this, it's a bug that is being fixed.
As a workaround for now, use incognito browser and/or clear all browser cache before trying again.
If all else fails - try to create a new IK instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i just noticed that the callback url in docusign  doesn't accept the fragment (#) and accept only  string is there a way to fix that probleme ?, or can you give me more guidance on how to procede. i'm trying to work with  JWT to grant consent.  thank you in advance.

Comment: For JWT Consent the return URI can be anything since you only have to do it once, so just use anything you want, like www.docusign.com, do it once, it's done and you can move on

Comment: But yes, # is not a valid character for redirectURI per the OATUH specifications, so that's not going to change.